# Computing permutations using a number of elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

I am trying to generate all possible permutations of a set of elements. The order doesn't matter, and elements may be present multiple times. The number of elements in each permutation is equal to the total number of elements.

A basic recursive algorithm for computing permutations following the schema (as I am writing in C++, the code will look similar to it):

```
elems = [0, 1, .., n-1];    // n unique elements. numbers only exemplary.
current = [];               // array of size n
perms(elems, current, 0);   // initial call

perms(array elems, array current, int depth) {
    if(depth == elems.size) print current;
    else {
        for(elem : elems) {
            current[depth] = elem;
            perms(elems, current, depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Would produce a large number of redundant sequences, e.g.:

```
0, 0, .., 0, 0
0, 0, .., 0, 1    // this
0, 0, .., 0, 2
.  .  .   .  . 
.  .  .   .  .
0, 0, .., 0, n-1
0, 0, .., 1, 0    // is the same as this
.  .  .   .  .    // many more redundant ones to follow
```

I tried to identify when exactly generating values can be skipped, but have so far not found nothing useful. I am sure I can find a way to hack around this, but I am also sure, that there is a rule behind this which I just haven't managed to see.

Edit: Possible solution+

```
elems = [0, 1, .., n-1];       // n unique elements. numbers only exemplary.
current = [];                  // array of size n
perms(elems, current, 0, 0);   // initial call

perms(array elems, array current, int depth, int minimum) {
    if(depth == elems.size) print current;
    else {
        for(int i=minimum; i<elems.size; i++) {
            current[depth] = elems[i];
            perms(elems, current, depth+1, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `std::next_permutation()`?

Comment: I didn't know such a function existed, I will look into it

Comment: The way I understood it, next_permutation will re-order the current elements to the "next permutation". As order is irrelevant in my case, it wouldn't work.

Comment: How can order be irrelevent if you're doing permutations? That's what permutation means! Maybe explain your problem better?

Comment: Maybe permutation is the wrong word, the reason why I am turning up here for help is because I couldn't find help searching the net. Permutation is the concept closest to what I do (in my head). I will try to formulate it this way: I have a set of n unique elements and want to know all possible sets of size n which feature 0 to n elements from the initial set. As sets have no order, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Do a web search for "next permutation". The recursive versions don't produce permutations in lexicographical order, but they use a bit less code. For lexicographical order, you need an iterative one that starts with an incrementing sequence of indices, usually 0 to n-1, and ends with a decrementing sequence of indices (n-1 to 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your first position varies from 0 to n.  Then make your second position to 1.  Then make your first position varies from 1 to n.  Then set second at 2 --> first from 2 to n and so on.

Comment: I will try to update my algorithm to include your suggestion, if you could tell me if it is the way you meant it, I would be very grateful

Comment: Doesn't this exclude any sequence with more than one 0?

Comment: the algorithm expands all nodes until the stop sequence triggers before building an actual solution, at which point it backtracks to the last calling instance, so it should work, I think.

Comment: The solution was what I had in mind, beautiful implementation by the way

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the crucial part =)

Answer (score 2):

I believe one such rule is to have the elements in each sequence be in non-decreasing order (or non-increasing, if you prefer).